# Is this a proper thread-safe Random wrapper?

Tags: random, f#, thread-safety

I am fairly inexperienced with threading and concurrency; to remedy that, I am currently working for fun on implementing a random-search algorithm in F#. I wrote a wrapper around the System.Random class, following ideas from existing C# examples - but as I am not sure how I would even begin to unit test this for faulty behavior, I'd like to hear what more experienced minds have to say, and if there are obvious flaws or improvements with my code, either due to F# syntax or threading misunderstanding:

```
open System
open System.Threading

type Probability() =

   static let seedGenerator = new Random()

   let localGenerator = 
      new ThreadLocal<Random>(
         fun _ -> 
            lock seedGenerator (
               fun _ -> 
                  let seed = seedGenerator.Next()
                  new Random(seed)))

   member this.Draw() = 
      localGenerator.Value.NextDouble()
```

My understanding of what this does: ThreadLocal ensures that for an instance, each thread receives its own instance of a Random, with its own random seed provided by a common, static Random. That way, even if multiple instances of the class are created close in time, they will receive their own seed, avoiding the problem of "duplicate" random sequences. The lock enforces that no two threads will get the same seed.

Does this look correct? Are there obvious issues?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your approach is pretty reasonable - using `ThreadLocal` gives you safe access to the `Random` and using a *master* random number generator to provide seeds means that you'll get random values even if you access it from multiple threads at similar time. It may not be random in the cryptographical sense, but should be fine for most other applications.

As for testing, this is quite tricky. If `Random` breaks, it will return 0 all the time, but that's just empirical experience and it is hard to say for how long you need to keep accessing it unsafely. The best thing I can suggest is to implement some simple randomness tests (some [simple ones are on WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness#Tests)) and access your type from multiple threads in a loop - though this is still quite bad test as it may not fail every time.

Aside, you don't need to use `type` to encapsulate this behaviour. It can be written as a function too:

```
open System
open System.Threading

module Probability =

   let Draw =
     // Create master seed generator and thread local value
     let seedGenerator = new Random()
     let localGenerator = new ThreadLocal<Random>(fun _ -> 
       lock seedGenerator (fun _ -> 
         let seed = seedGenerator.Next()
         new Random(seed)))
     // Return function that uses thread local random generator
     fun () ->
       localGenerator.Value.NextDouble()
```

Comment: Can you add an example on how to use it?

Comment: Just call `Probability.Draw ()`!

Comment: If I plan to call it in a loop, should I instance it before hand?

Comment: You don't have to - the trick is that this happens when the `Draw` value is first accessed - `Draw` is a value that is initialized once, but it's initialized to a function that can be called repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

This feels wrong-headed.  Why not just use a singleton (only ever create one Random instance, and lock it)?

If real randomness is a concern, then maybe see RNGCryptoServiceProvider, which is threadsafe.

Comment: I always tend to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider for the more random distribution too.

Comment: The issue that's trying to be avoided is having two separate Random instances having the same seed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a performance bottleneck, I think something like

```
let rand = new Random()

let rnext() = 
     lock rand (
        fun () -> 
           rand.next())
```

will be easier to understand, but I think your method should be fine.

Comment: The problem with code like this is if you generate several objects in quick succession. Because all of them will have the same seed. Or did you mean that those are globals?

Comment: @svick - Point was why generate a whole stack of randoms - this is just one random which you can access from multiple threads.  It is much simpler and unless you need a ridiculous number of random numbers it should be fine.  If rands are a bottleneck you are better off with a different generator to get speed anyway

Comment: Well, the expensive bit is the lock for every random number.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go with the OO approach, then your code may be fine (I won't say 'it is' fine as I am not too smart to understand OO :) ). But in case you want to go the functional way it would be as simple as something like:

```
type Probability = { Draw : unit -> int }

let probabilityGenerator (n:int) = 
    let rnd = new Random()
    Seq.init n (fun _ -> new Random(rnd.Next()))
    |> Seq.map (fun r -> { Draw = fun () -> r.Next() })
    |> Seq.toList
```

Here you can use the function probabilityGenerator to generate as much as "Porbability" type object and then distribute them to various threads which can work on them in parallel.
The important thing here is that we are not introducing lock etc in the core type i.e probability and it becomes the responsibility of the consumer how they want to distribute it across threads.

Comment: I would use `Seq.toArray` instead of `Seq.toList`, so that the caller can use array indices as thread ids.

Comment: This function generate n items for a same thread (calling thread)

Comment: Yes, but an array is safe for readonly access from multiple threads, so this solution could be used equally as a single or multi-threaded solution.