# Thread-local objects for Task.WaitAll

Tags: .net, f#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a small number of tasks, and I want to use `Task.WaitAll` to run them in parallel. This is what I have by now:

```
type System.Threading.Tasks.Task with
  static member WaitAll(ts) =
    Task.WaitAll [| for t in ts -> t :> Task |]

let processf p fs =
  let rand = Random ()
  let ts = fs |> Array.map (fun f -> Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> p(f, rand)))
  Task.WaitAll(ts)
  ts |> Array.map (fun t -> t.Result)
```

The problem is that `Random` is not thread-safe (`Random` class is chosen for illustration purpose only). How can I create an object for each thread rather than create an object for each `Task`, which is wasteful?

**EDIT:**

Using `ThreadStatic` like Brian's and Daniel's suggestions is a good approach, especially with a factory class. However, I prefer `ThreadLocal` suggested by Reed and Tomas because it looks simpler. I agree that using a master `Random` is a bit over-complex. The following is a mixed solution I keep for future reference:

```
let processf p fs =
  use localRand = new ThreadLocal<_>(
                       fun() -> Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
  let ts = fs |> Array.map (fun f -> 
                          Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> p(f, localRand.Value)))
  Task.WaitAll(ts)
  ts |> Array.map (fun t -> t.Result)
```

Comment: Isn't creating a thread local is same as creating a new Random object for each task such that it becomes `p(f, new Random(currentthreadID))`, which is much more clear approach

Comment: `ThreadLocal` *is* a per-thread factory class. It's nothing more than a wrapper around a `ThreadStatic` field, with some additional overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your thread-specific state in a factory class and mark it `ThreadStatic`.

```
type PerThread =

  [<ThreadStatic; DefaultValue>]
  static val mutable private random : Random

  static member Random = 
    match PerThread.random with
    | null -> PerThread.random <- Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    | _ -> ()
    PerThread.random
```

Then you can do:

```
let process p fs =
  let ts = fs |> Array.map (fun f -> 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> p(f, PerThread.Random)))
  Task.WaitAll(ts)
  ts |> Array.map (fun (t: Task) -> t.Result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ThreadLocal<'T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx#Y0) to store the Random instance.  This will provide a thread-local random value, which can be disposed of upon completion of your tasks.

Answer (score 2):

A [recent F# question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789470/is-this-a-proper-thread-safe-random-wrapper) implements exactly what you're looking for.

Using thread-local (thread-static) storage is the way to go, but you should be careful - when all threads start at the same time, there is a chance that they'll also get the same initial seed. To solve this problem, the implementation above uses a *master* `Random` protected by a lock that is used to generate seeds for individual threads.

Comment: That solution seems overly complex. `CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` seems like a reasonable seed value.

Comment: @Daniel - `ManagedThreadId` should be a reasonable alternative, although you may get the same result if you run the program repeatedly (I think .NET often tends to use the same thread IDs when running the same program repeatedly)

Comment: If he needs unique random values across multiple executions of his program, that's a very specific/special requirement indeed!

Comment: @Daniel - That's a fairly reasonable requirement e.g. for a game - you don't want monsters behave the same every time you play! (That's why `Random` uses current time by default...)

Answer (score 1):

You could declare 'rand' as a [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx).  Alternatively, there are some APIs in the TPL that allow for TLS; I don't know them all, but see e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997393%28VS.100%29.aspx), may be jumping off point to find others.  (Hopefully others will post more details or refine this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you event need Thread Local. You can create the new Random object in each task using the current thread ID. 
Ex:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> p(f, new Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))))
```

Which I think is much more simple and easy to understand rather than tracking the Thread local variable.

Comment: Suppose that Random is a class which is really expensive to initialize. Then ThreadLocal approach reducing the number of instances needed is of my desire.

Comment: In case a object is expensive to create, then you should be using Object polling technique.